# Can windows 11 calculator results be saved to a Userform Textbox?

Tags: windows, shell, textbox, calculator, userform

Require code to take windows 11 calculator results and place in the active Userform Textbox.

Steps: Call the calculate by Shell command and somehow program the results to be save in VBA.

Searched the Internet without finding a solution or good sample code, that would help me design a UserForm Calculator.   Similar to the DatePicker userform designed by Trevor Eyre.

Comment: Just guessing here, but does highlighting the answer and pressing Ctrl-C (for copy) , and then in VBA find a function that accesses the clipboard and "pastes" it into you running calculation. (Not a VBA expert, but such a funcdtion almost certainly exists). Good luck.

Comment: Change one of your low "watcher" count tags to VBA. Then you'll get an answer. Good luck.